# my.ini and mysql_connect encoding

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Does PHP’s `mysql_connect()` function use the MySQL *my.ini* configuration file when it establishes the connection to the MySQL server instance? 
It seems not.

I have the table with the UTF-8 encoding and the PHP script which connects to the database and inserts data in UTF-8 encoding.

By default the `mysql_client_encoding()` returns `latin1`.
When I use `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")` or `mysql_set_charset("utf8")` after establishing the connecion, all works fine.

I would like to know is there other way to force use correct encoding for exchange data with MySQL from PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there's any other way of defaulting the MySQL client encoding setting from the client side (with a php ini setting or similar).

From the server side you may find that the PHP client inherits the MySQL variable `character_set_client` but I'm unable to confirm that.